# How to delete the contents of a file in java?

Tags: java

I am generating random numbers and putting that in a file and from that file I m reading the values. Now while reading it is reading all the values which has been put to the file again rather than reading the last added value. So what I want is to delete the contents of the file before writing any random number to it again so that when it reads from it, it will only read the last added value.

Comment: Please show some research. Simply searching Java documentation for how to write in a file should give you an answer: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this all at the same time via `RandomAccessFile,` just call `RandomAccessFile.setLength(0).`

If you're doing it via a `FileOutputStream` or `FileWriter,` just create a new one without the `append` parameter, or with that parameter set to `false.

Comment: so do I have to set the parameter of append to "false" everytime before writing into the file or only once?? becoz i have used this constructor once only and it still reading all the values... :-|

Comment: Set it to false every time you want to clear the file, which is what you asked about.

Answer (score -1):

Write an empty string into the file like below

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);
writer.print("");
writer.close();
```

Comment: You don't need to write anything. Just creating the `PrintWriter` like that is sufficient.